# SELECT INTO more than one variable

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create stored procedure, get some data from database, and then put that data into variables.

Right now i am using this:

```
DECLARE @CurrentRbr int;
        SET @CurrentRbr = 
        (
           SELECT Max(Rbr) + 1 As CurrentRbr 
           FROM Orders 
           WHERE OrderID=@OrderID 
        )
```

I would like to have few more variables:

```
DECLARE @OrderAdress varchar(50), @OrderCity varchar (20)
```

Can I do something like, (this of course does not work):

```
SET @CurrentRbr,@OrderAdress,@OrderCity = 
        (
           SELECT Max(Rbr) + 1 As CurrentRbr,OrderAdress,OrderCity 
           FROM Orders 
           WHERE OrderID=@OrderID 
        )
```

Comment: Instead of `SET`, you assign variable values with `SELECT` as long as only 1 row is returned by the query like `SELECT @CurrentRbr=Max(Rbr) + 1,@OrderAdress=OrderAdress,@OrderCity=OrderCity FROM Orders WHERE OrderID=@OrderID;`

Comment: Thank you. Can you create answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select` is a better than `Set` for put that data into variables.

```
DECLARE @CurrentRbr int,@OrderAdress varchar(50), @OrderCity varchar (20)

       SELECT @CurrentRbr = Max(Rbr) + 1 ,
              @OrderAdress=OrderAdress,
              @OrderCity=OrderCity 
       FROM Orders 
       WHERE OrderID=@OrderID 
       Group by OrderAdress, OrderCity
```

if you use one variable you don't need `SET` like below:

```
DECLARE @CurrentRbr int = (
           SELECT Max(Rbr) + 1 As CurrentRbr 
           FROM Orders 
           WHERE OrderID=@OrderID 
        )
```

[You can read another form of use variable in SQL click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
I hope you for the best

Comment: Your first statement will fail as it use `Max` along with other columns and no `group by`...